# How to get an a value for an particular record only (by ignoring filter condition ) in django ORM

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

For the the below model,

```
class Comments(models.Model)
    comment_text= models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    type        = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    date        = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
```

In my views,  I am getting the latest comments with text>125 .

now If the comment type is "System", I have to display those comments by ignoring the filter condition (even though they are less than 125 chars) with regulars comments properly sorted by latest

how to achieve it ?

In short the filter condition shouldn't apply on comments of type 'System' (but should apply on all other comments)and it should should appear in the results with all other comments in the sorted order.

```
comments=Comments.objects.filter(comment_text__length__gte=125).order_by("-date")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Q object.

```py
from django.db.models import Q

comments=Comments.objects.filter(Q(type="System")|Q(comment_text__length__gte=125)).order_by("-date")
```

Comment: Thanks,  suppose if need to add additional filter  conditions with the above , how should I add ??

Comment: You can further club multiple Q objects, they can be combined together as below:

 , representing AND
 | representing OR
 ~ operator for negated (NOT)
 

Refer official doc for more on complex lookups with Q object:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects